# Check if file will be changed after package update

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

I'm using CentOS 7.4.
Here I have `/etc/bashrc` filename and it's from `setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch` package:

```
# rpm -qf /etc/bashrc
setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch
```

I've changed it and interested now, if file will be rewritten/removed after package update. How can I check it, with `rpm` command may be?

Answer (score 0):

This will check changes:

```
rpm -V setup
```

When altered, rpm on upgrade create either rpmsave or rpmnew file. The difference is described here https://serverfault.com/a/48819

How to query the flag is described here: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2003-October/msg00134.html

Comment: mm, your command shows me nothing. But in your link I've found construction `rpm -q --qf '[%{filenames}: %{fileflags}\n]' setup` and it showed my file flags. I'm not sure I've understood clearly what is that, can you give me a hint how to find info about these flags?

Comment: hmm it should  be rpm -V setup   (name of the package which owns that config).

Comment: ```[root@XXX ~]# rpm -qf /etc/bashrc 
setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch
[root@XXX ~]# rpm -V setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch
[root@XXX ~]# rpm -V setup-2.8.71-7.el7
[root@XXX ~]# rpm -V setup-2.8.71-7```

Answer (score 0):

`rpm -V` will show if RPM thinks you changed it (as noted in anther answer). I'm not 100% sure it will save your changes across upgrades, because that is not normally a file the user should edit, so it's probably not declared to be a configuration file. The RPM builder needs to explicitly tag the file(s) that way in the specfile.

A better question back would be why are you editing that file? Dropping a file into `/etc/profile.d/` is a much cleaner and supported solution, assuming your changes only apply to logged-in users.